# Multidimensional array to ListView.. how?

Tags: java, android, listview, multidimensional-array

I have a query result set which I like to edit first and then put it to my ListView. Without editing my data first, I could use SimpleCursorAdapter like that:

```
ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
    this, 
    R.layout.list_item, 
    mCursor, 
    new String[] { "address", "city" }, 
    new int[] { R.id.address, R.id.zip_city });
this.setListAdapter(adapter);
```

But now, I put everything in a multidimensional array like that:

```
if(mCursor.isFirst()) {

        //create a new array
        String[][] listData = new String[mCursor.getCount()][3];

        int i = 0;
        do {

            listData[i] = new String[] {
                mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex("address")),
                mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex("zip")) + " " + mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex("city")),
                calculateDistance(Double.parseDouble(mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex("diff"))))
                };

            i++;

        } while(mCursor.moveToNext());

    }
```

So my problem is now, I have no idea how to put this to my ListView. Could someone help me here? Sorry for my bad english and Java knowledge. :)

Answer (score 0):

Either write your own adapter class, extending `BaseAdapter`, that works with your array, or switch to a different data structure, such as a `MatrixCursor`.

Answer (score 0):

HOW TO USE A LISTVIEW WITH A MULTI-DIMENSION ARRAY

Guys, the simplest way is as follows -

In the calling activity, let us call it FirstActivity,  you declare the multiple dimension array as public static

`public static MyArray[][];`

In the second activity you refer to this array using -

`FirstActivity.MyArray`

Now create a single dimension array that reads just one column from the multi dimension array using a loop eg

`for(int i = 0; i < FirstActivity.MyArray.length; i++){
            SingleArray[i] = FirstActivity.MyArray[i][0];}`

Then use an adapter to bind the list to the SingleArray

`setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, SingleArray));`

Just remember to clear the arrays each time, so they do not retain values from before.

Regards

Craig Paardekooper